# Change the level of 'greyed-out-ness' of a html bootstrap button and javascript

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a form submission button that is greyed out by default, and is only active when a checkbox is checked.

The button uses the bootstrap btn-success class (so its green), but when deactivate it is still pretty green and could be mistaken for an active button. Is there a way to control how greyed out it is with javascript?

**My current code:**

**Button:**

```
<input type="submit" id="postme1" value="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-block">
```

**Script:**

```
 <script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
    $(window).load(function(){
    if($(this).prop('checked')){
             $('#postme1').removeAttr('disabled');
        }
        else {
            $('#postme1').attr("disabled","disabled");   

        }

$('#checky1').click(function(){

    if($(this).prop('checked')){
         $('#postme1').removeAttr('disabled');
    }

    else {
        $('#postme1').attr("disabled","disabled");   
    }
});
});//]]>  

</script>
```

Any help or direction is appreciated thanks

Comment: Why not change the actual class of the button to btn-default (as well as being disabled)? Either way, you're looking to change the opacity. `[disabled]` buttons have `opacity:.65` so you can try from .65 -.99 for more transparency.

Comment: Javascript should not be the answer for this. If you want to change the styles change the CSS or [customize bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need javascript, just change the CSS.  Look for this bit (assuming bootstrap 3)

```
.btn-success.disabled,
.btn-success[disabled],
fieldset[disabled] .btn-success,
.btn-success.disabled:hover,
.btn-success[disabled]:hover,
fieldset[disabled] .btn-success:hover,
.btn-success.disabled:focus,
.btn-success[disabled]:focus,
fieldset[disabled] .btn-success:focus,
.btn-success.disabled:active,
.btn-success[disabled]:active,
fieldset[disabled] .btn-success:active,
.btn-success.disabled.active,
.btn-success[disabled].active,
fieldset[disabled] .btn-success.active {
  background-color: #5cb85c;
  border-color: #4cae4c;
}
```

And change the colour to be what you like, either in the CSS directly, or by overriding this selector in your own stylesheet.

UPDATE:
If you want to change the opacity, rather than change the colour to be more grey then you can do that using the `.btn.disabled` selector

Comment: that's not where its happening.

Comment: @Carrie can you elaborate?  I've just taken this section from Chrome tools looking at the examples on GetBootstrap. The OP says he's using btn-success, although the code doesn't show this.

Comment: Oh I see, you want to change the opacity instead?  This would work too :)

Comment: That's not the actual code that is referring to what OP is asking about, its line 2025

Comment: Noted, thanks.  The downside with going too opaque is the text becomes less readable. Perhaps changing the colour to something closer to grey will look better.

Comment: is the 'fieldset[disabled]' refering to the #postme1 checkbox that enables the button? Would I have to change the name of this? Does this mean I don't need the javascript anymore or?

Comment: The fieldset[disabled] rule(s) mean that if the disabled attribute is applied to the surrounding fieldset element then apply this style to any .btn-success elements within the fieldset (there will be similar rules for other element types but this rule just applies to btn-success).  So it has the effect of letting you show the disabled style on an entire fieldset in one go.

Comment: There are a lot of selector rules here, but the one that will most often apply is just .btn-success[disabled] - a .btn-success class with a disabled attribute. So you may need javascript to remove/apply the disabled attribute depending on your business logic, but not to adjust the style of a disabled button.